# Comparing times with time zones in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.1.4

**tl;dr;** I am getting a date & time from the user that comes into the controller from a form (via params) like this:

```
pickuptime = params[:appointment][:pickuptime]
(byebug) pickuptime
"01/06/2015 7:26 PM"
```

and I need to make sure it is in the future so that customers can't create appointments in the past, and I have the customer's time_zone stored in the database because customers may be in different places.

**Detail:**

I am getting a time in my controller via a form:

```
pickuptime = params[:appointment][:pickuptime]
(byebug) pickuptime
"01/06/2015 7:26 PM"
```

I then convert it to a `DateTime` so that I can build an appointment record:

```
pickuptime = DateTime.strptime(pickuptime, "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p")
@appointment = @car.appointments.build(garage_id: garage_id, pickuptime: pickuptime)
```

My `Appointment` model has a validation that ensures that you cannot create an appointment in the past:

```
def pickuptime_is_in_future
  if pickuptime < Time.current
    errors.add(:pickuptime, "Appointment must be in the future")
  end
end
```

I would like to take into account the customer's time_zone (`@car.garage.time_zone`), which is stored in the database, when building the appointment, e.g.

```
pry(main)> Garage.first.time_zone
Garage Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "garages".* FROM "garages"   ORDER BY "garages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

Right now this is not working. When I create an appointment for 1 minute in the future, I get the following:

```
(byebug) pickuptime
Tue, 06 Jan 2015 19:22:00 UTC +00:00
(byebug) Time.current
Wed, 07 Jan 2015 00:21:53 UTC +00:00
```

which causes the validation to fail, despite the fact that the appointment was created in the future and should therefore succeed.

Any guidance on how to implement this correctly would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [in_time_zone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-in_time_zone).

See https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/168-dealing-with-timezones-effectively-in-rails & http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails for good advice on working with timezones in rails.